# In MySQL JOIN means which join perform..?

Tags: mysql, join

It's to confusing, I have query where I have write JOIN with multiple table then which type of join it'll perform..?

**For example :**

```
SELECT
    b.*
FROM
    tbl_bookings b
JOIN tbl_users ua ON ua.id = b.act_id
JOIN tbl_users uc ON uc.id = b.cust_id
JOIN tbl_venue v ON b.venue_id = v.venue_id
WHERE
    b.act_id = 4
```

Can any one please let me know by which type of join it'll perform..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` equals to an [`INNER JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) . They are functionally equivalent, but `INNER JOIN` can be a bit clearer to read, especially if the query contains other type of `JOIN`

For something other than `INNER JOIN` you should specify the join you want.

[`LEFT JOIN` / `RIGHT JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) which are the same as `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` .

Those are just different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: They're not merely functionally equivalent. In MySQL, they are the exact same thing.

Comment: In every RDBMS that I know they are the same, and I think my answer is clear about that. I didn't meant to point on a difference , just to say that its neater to write `INNER` .

Answer (score 1):

It will perform `INNER JOIN`. It is good to write `INNER JOIN` when you have different types of joins in query.